# SharePoint list, catalog and layouts

Tags: site-collection, layouts, style-library, catalog

We are using SharePoint 2013.

Would like to know:-

1. Is the _catalog folder common to all webs in site collection?, please explain.
2. Is the Style Library common to all webs in site collection?, please explain.
3. Is the Layouts folder common to all webs in site collection?, please explain.
4. What are the libraries/folders/things that are common to all webs in site collection?

Answer (score -2):

1. _catalog is a is available to current SPWeb
2. Style library is available only to current SPWeb
3. _layouts folder is available to all websites in WebApplication
4. If you want any site to have access to a file, add it to _Layouts.

Comment: is _catalog common to all webs in  sitecollection? I dont think so. because each web has its own _catalog/masterpage, etc.

Comment: To many wrongs in this answer! Catalogs is site collection specific, Layouts is global. Style library should be used as site collection specific (on the root web)